# welcome.tar file missing in web2py

Tags: web2py

When I try to create a new application in web2py , I get an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/web2py/gluon/admin.py", line 175, in app_create
    w2p_unpack('welcome.w2p', path)
  File "/web2py/gluon/fileutils.py", line 322, in w2p_unpack
    tarfile = open(tarname, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/web2py/welcome.tar'
```

But I have found out that there is no such file present there. Why welcome.tar is missing? How would I get it? Please suggest.

Comment: Where are you running web2py?

Answer (score 0):

The message says "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied".  That's not the Python error message for a missing file; that would be "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".  Seems likely the file does exist but you don't have permission to access it.  Try again via `sudo` or logged in as a privileged user.

Comment: I have logged is as a root user and it is still not showing that file.

Comment: You might try listing the contents of the zip or tar file itself to see if the file is present there, rather than trying to find the file once extracted (that could conceivably still be inaccessible to you for other reasons).

Comment: I run this command : sudo unzip -l web2py_src.zip | grep tar
But no results found for welcome.tar

Comment: Looking at your original error message again -- the `open` call is in mode `wb` which means "write".  The tar file is being written, not read.  You must not have adequate write permission.

Comment: Test the simplest permission issue. Try `touch /web2py/testfile` -- does that produce an error?